# CollapsingToolbarLayout expansion not working with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

The behavior of CollapsibleToolbarLayout with regards to the RecyclerView seems broken. When setting a value for

app:layout_scrollFlags

If you do not use "scroll|enterAlways", the Collabsible layout will never expand. It will always contract, but when you pull down, it does not expand anymore, so it just gets locked to the top.

If you use "scroll|enterAlways", it works as expected, meaning it instantly expands the header to its full height whenever you scroll down.

Without knowing anymore, it seems as if the Collapsible layout cannot properly determine when the RecyclerView is at the top of the list, as that is the criteria for when it should expand to full height in the other cases.

Here is the layout that I am testing with. The java code isn't really important, it is just populating the recyclerview with dummy data and using a LinearLayoutManager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar_id"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try with `scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed`. This way the toolbar should always enter in the collapsed mode, and then expand when you reach the top of the sibling view.

Comment: @m vai Hey, after experimenting with flags for few hours I came up with the exact same solution, however when toolbars enters in collapsed mode half of it is under statusbar. Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Minas spend another few hours experimenting with the horrible "android:fitsSystemWindows" attribute :-)

Comment: @m vai haha I'm doing exactly that, however I need to fit an image inside CollapsingToolbarLayout under the statusbar, so removing it is not an option

Comment: @Minas eventually you will make it work, you just have to find the right true/false combination.

Comment: @m vai ok, thanks :)  Will try with some different combinations. Currently toolbar is finally bellow the statusbar and statusbar is white :D hope to somehow make statusbar transparent again.

Comment: Seems like a true which should be false instead!

Comment: turns out the only solution is to set it false for CoordinatorLayout, but in this case statusbar is not transparent and image is bellow it :(

Comment: Finally found a solution! Set margin top for the toolbar programmatically to the status bar height

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show a list with RecyclerView under the AppBarLayout you should place the RecyclerView XML under

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar_id"
    app:contentScrim="@color/white"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```